# How to build query to check if a string built from number of rows appears more than once?

Tags: android, arrays, sqlite

bit of a difficult one to explain, but here we go:

I have a database table which looks a bit like this (VERY simplified for the purposes of this question);

```
_id | area_link | text1 | text2 | text3 | text4
1          1      this     is       one    example
2          1      this     is     another  example
3          2      this     is       one    example
4          2      this     is     another  example
5          2      this     is     another  example
```

So I can build a query to find data WHERE area_link equals 2, but I want to somehow create an array which looks like this:

```
thisisoneexample
thisisanotherexample
```

but that does not result in this (which is what I would have with a simple query):

```
thisisoneexample
thisisanotherexample
thisisanotherexample
```

Here is an example of my actual query in database helper class:

```
public Cursor fetchComponentSpecForArea(long areaId, String componentType, String specSaved) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor =
            rmDb.query(true, DAMAGED_COMPONENTS_TABLE, new String[] {
                    AREA_LINK,
                    COMPONENT_TYPE,
                    MANUFACTURER,
                    TEXT1,
                    TEXT2,
                    TEXT3,
                    TEXT4,
                    NOTES_SPEC,
                    SPEC_SAVED}, 
                    AREA_LINK + " = " + areaId + " AND " + COMPONENT_TYPE + " = ? AND " + SPEC_SAVED + " = ?", 
                    new String[] {componentType, specSaved}, 
                    null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

And an example of how I call this in the main code:

```
        final Cursor componentSpecForAreaCursor = (Cursor) rmDbHelper.fetchComponentSpecForArea(areaId, componentType, specSaved);
        if (componentSpecForAreaCursor.moveToFirst()){
            String manufacturer = RMUtilities.notEmpty(componentSpecForAreaCursor.getString(componentSpecForAreaCursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.MANUFACTURER)), "");
            String text1 = RMUtilities.notEmpty(componentSpecForAreaCursor.getString(componentSpecForAreaCursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.TEXT1)), "");
            String text2 = RMUtilities.notEmpty(componentSpecForAreaCursor.getString(componentSpecForAreaCursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.TEXT2)), "");
            String text3 = RMUtilities.notEmpty(componentSpecForAreaCursor.getString(componentSpecForAreaCursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.TEXT3)), "");
            String text4 = RMUtilities.notEmpty(componentSpecForAreaCursor.getString(componentSpecForAreaCursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.TEXT4)), "");
            String notes_spec = RMUtilities.notEmpty(componentSpecForAreaCursor.getString(componentSpecForAreaCursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.NOTES_SPEC)), "");
            rmDbHelper.saveDamagedComponentSpec(componentId, manufacturer, text1, text2, text3, text4, notes_spec);
        }
```

So I guess I have to:

```
create an array,
query the database,
if cursor > 0 then go to first and:
build a string from the relevant database fields,
put this into array
build next string from the relevant database fields,
check if this matches any of entries in array if not:
put this into array
```

etc, but could do with some help!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you even get 2 x `thisisanotherexample`? You seem to have `DISTINCT` query mode enabled already in your code - that should prevent duplicate rows already.

Comment: Hi Zapl, ahh didn't know it did that.  I have yet to write the query so haven't tested.  Update shortly!

Comment: Unfortunately, the DISTINCT doesn't help as there are two database entries where text1 && text2 && text3 && text4 are the same BUT which have different _id's (and are therefore seen as disctinct).  So my question still stands!

Answer (score 0):

Try using Pattern and Matcher objects. Then call the `.find()` method of the matcher object and perform the actions you want!

Here is a link from the Official docs that can help you: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Thanks for response Παύλος, may have a simpler solution from Zapl, but will look at yours if this doesn't work as expected.  Regards.